# Saving content of form in array

Tags: php, arrays, forms

I have a form where names from a SQL-database are listed. After each name there is a textfield for a grade. I want the grades and names to be saved in arrays. It already works with the names, but the array for the grades just gets filled with the content in the last textfield.

```
$Requete  = "SELECT `vorname`, `nachname` FROM `lernende`";
    $Result   = mysql_query($Requete,$db);
    $grade     = array();
    $vorname  = array();
    $nachname = array();
    $counter  = 0;

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($Result))
    {

        echo '<p>', $row["vorname"]," ", $row["nachname"], " ", '<label>Note: <input type="text" name="note"/></label></p>';
        $grade[$counter] = $_POST['note'];
        $vorname[$counter]    = $row["vorname"];
        $nachname[$counter]    = $row["nachname"];
        $counter = $counter + 1;

    }
```

What is wrong with my code? I've just started learning php and have no idea how to solve this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You hvae to change this line of code:

```
echo '<p>', $row["vorname"]," ", $row["nachname"], " ", '<label for="note-'.$counter.'">Note:</label> <input id="note-'.$counter.'" type="text" name="note[]"/></label></p>';
```

However, your code is not the finest I'd say. Start learning working with arrays as shown on http://php.net/array and start with clean HTML as described at http://de.selfhtml.org/ (since you are German speaking).

Comment: thank you very much for your help :)
yeah, I think I have a lot to learn.. thanks for the links

Answer (score 0):

Give the grade fields different names, or name them as an array: `<input name="note[]">`

Answer (score 0):

In your code you have  $_POST['note'], which is getting repeated for each row, 
for name field and note filed you should be attach $counter to distinguish these input fields.